# Как распределить 6 картинок через flex (пример ниже)

Tags: css

Помогите распределить картинки как показано на примере ниже через flexbox
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я конечно не претендую на 100% правильность но вот так вариант ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PLeeJQ

Comment: А как можно сделать чтобы блок был шириной в 100%?

Comment: щас проверь ссылку снова

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/full/PLeeJQ  полноэкранное дэмо

Answer (score 1):

Особенностью flexbox является то, что изменять положение блоков можно только по одной оси, либо по горизонтальной, либо по вертикальной. В данном случае у вас есть два варианта:

1. Использовать css grid, который позволяет манипулировать блоками в двух осях
2. У вас будет один общий контейнер для всех картинок. Он будет содержать два дочерних контейнера: первый - содержит холодильник и смартфоны, а второй - ванны и комплектующие, смарт часы, ноутбуки и конструкторы. Flexbox-ы в первом и во втором дочерних блоках будут различаться.

Comment: С учётом того, что ТС код в вопрос добавлять не собирается, твой ответ является очень даже пояснительным. Лови плюс